# Links from static html in Grails

Tags: grails

My app renders html, created by external program and placed in a folder outside the app  (so that it wouldn't disappear after redeployment), and this html contains links to other files in that folder. I can change the links, but how to get them work?

This is how the html is rendered now:

```
def url = createLink(controller: 'job', action: 'renderResults', params: [resultsPath:resultsPath])
render(contentType: 'text/html', text: "<script>window.location.href='$url'</script>")
..

def renderResults (String resultsPath){
    def htmlContent = new File(resultsPath).text
    render (text: htmlContent, contentType:"text/html", encoding:"UTF-8")
}
```

This one does not work (suppose renderImage is ok)

```
<a href="${createLink(controller : 'job', action:'renderImage', params: [imagePath:'C:/Users/../image.jpg'])}">Link</a>
```

even if I try to render html in a gsp view:

```
def url = createLink(controller: 'job', action: 'renderResults', params:[resultsPath:resultsPath])
render(view:"index/results", text: "<script>window.location.href='$url'</script>")
```

with only {$text} in results.gsp.

All this may seem crazy, so please don't hesitate to tell me about that - I'm just a newbie.

**UPD:** My question is somewhat vague, so I'll try sum it up: is there any way to create a link from an html to some resource located outside the app? Dynamic grails links do not work in html - I guess, because it is not a view. And simple static links (like "/home/images/test.img", "../../images/test.img") inevitably lead somewhere into app folder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a context to your application server (tomcat for instance) so you can just link to the HTML directly? Something like this: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-configure-context-xml-aliases-for-Tomcat-7-td4632149.html

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, thank you, didn't even know about such a possibility. I'll check it out!